# django: mod_wsgi fails to open log file inside project directory

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my project using mod_wsgi. Unfortunately I get:

```
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64] Exception in WSGI handler: 
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/home/project/project/wsgi/project.wsgi", line 26, in application
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     return handler(environ, start_response)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.5.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 230, in __call__
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     self.load_middleware()
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.5.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 33, in load_middleware
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.5.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     self._setup()
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.5.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.5.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 73, in __init__
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.5.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     __import__(name)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/home/project/project/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     logging.config.fileConfig(settings.LOG_CONFIG)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/config.py", line 84, in fileConfig
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/config.py", line 152, in _install_handlers
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     h = apply(klass, args)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/handlers.py", line 109, in __init__
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/handlers.py", line 61, in __init__
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 772, in __init__
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64]     stream = open(filename, mode)
[Wed Oct 27 15:32:33 2010] [error] [client 10.13.3.64] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'project.log'
```

I have an entry for my project inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/:

```
SetEnv app_settings project.config.production
WSGIDaemonProcess project user=project group=project threads=1 processes=1 home=/home/project/project python-path=/home/project
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName project.internal
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/project/project/wsgi/project.wsgi
        WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

My logs should be stored inside the project directory. I have investigated it a little and just before project.log is supposed to be opened I run os.getcwd(), which returned `/`. Can anyone tell me, what I might have misconfigured that this happens?

Comment: Look at `sys.argv[0]` as well.

Comment: Could you post what's in your `project.wsgi`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not much of an answer, but I set my site up to only use absolute pathnames, pulling in the base paths from `settings.py`.  You can have variables in `settings.py` that aren't official Django settings names, and as long as you name them using ALLCAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES style, it will let you import those with `import settings`.

IIRC, daemons in general should use absolute pathnames.  Apparently, using relative pathnames can be a security hole.

Comment: Using absolute path in logging config worked (used by python logging system), but I am pretty certain, that relative path can be used too - on other server we had django deployed that way. I'd like to do that same way.

Comment: Then you may need to do an `os.chdir()` in your `project.wsgi` file; maybe `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`?  The key point is that relative paths are *fragile*; you can run your program from anywhere by executing `/home/project/project/wsgi/project.wsgi`.  So can there really be a guarantee that the working directory will always be the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about paths, it's about permissions.

The apache user is trying to create that log file, so you should give it write permissions on that directory.

Comment: ... and all the parent directories upwards in the tree